# How to reverse chronological order with getSymbols in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, quantmod

I download some stock data with quantmod and retrieve the closing prices:

```
require(quantmod)
tickers<-c('AAPL','GOOGL')
getSymbols(tickers, from="2014-03-01")
close <- do.call(merge, lapply(tickers, function(x) Cl(get(x))))
head(close)

AAPL.Close GOOGL.Close
2014-03-03     527.76     1202.69
2014-03-04     531.24     1214.91
2014-03-05     532.36     1218.26
2014-03-06     530.75     1219.61
2014-03-07     530.44     1214.79
2014-03-10     530.92     1211.57
```

Is there a way to run getSymbols so that the most recent dates output is first?

Comment: how about `close[nrow(close):1,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final result is the [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/) object. xts is "fanatic" about order. But you can access the data with function `coredata` (for data part) and `time` for time vector.

Try for example:

```
res <- data.frame( time = time(close), coredata(close))
res <- res[nrow(res):1,]
```

Comment: Every time series library should respect the time order - no doubt about that :)